# Haml form that is expecting $end?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, haml

Hi I'm really new to Rails, and Haml of course and I've been trying to figure this out for couple days already.

when rendering pages with this partial I get error:

`app/views/todos/_form.html.haml:19: syntax error,unexpected keyword_end, expecting $end`

(Please excuse my indentation errors, I didn't have an option to copy and paste)
_form.html.haml contents:

```
1 = form_tag :todo do |f|
2     %br
3         = f.label :done
4             = f.check_box :done
5         = f.label :title
6         = f.text_field :title
7     %br
8         = f.label :urgent
9             = f.check_box :urgent
10     %br
11         = f.label :important
12            = f.check_box :important
13     %br
14         = f.label :description
15     %br
16         = f.text_area :description
17     %br
18         = f.submit "Save"
19
```

Comment: is that the indentation you are using? (the = f.check_box lines stick out to me)

Comment: @CodeGnome `= form_tag` on line 1 is correct, as you want to display the form an it's contents on the page. The sub form elements are just passed to the ruby form block, then line 1 renders the lot into to the page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In HAML, you cannot have any direct sub elements to a `=` unless it's a block. As an `=` is ruby code and not part of the html template as such.

If you want sub elements to a `=` thay will need to passed to a ruby block like the `= form_tag do |f|` does.

So it's your check_box's that are causing this error.

In this example I would move both the form helpers to a single line like this:

```
= form_tag :todo do |f|
  %br
    = f.label :done, f.check_box(:done)
    = f.label :title
    = f.text_field :title
  %br
    = f.label :urgent, f.check_box(:urgent)
  %br
    = f.label :important, f.check_box(:important)
  %br
    = f.label :description
    = f.text_area :description
  %br
    = f.submit "Save"
```

You could also tell the label helper to accept a block by adding `do` at the end of the method call:

```
= form_tag :todo do |f|
  %br
    = f.label :done do
      = f.check_box(:done)
    ...
```

Or even use an haml element instead of the rails form helper to make the label:

```
= form_tag :todo do |f|
  %br
    %label{:for => 'done'}
      = f.check_box :done
    ...
```

Comment: complistic you nailed it thank you! how can I nest these checkboxes in labels is there other syntax for this? I couldn't find it on Haml reference site.

Comment: @sgp667, I have added a second way to do this. Both ways should nest though, as the first way sends the html of the checkbox to the second argument of the label helper.

Comment: You can do "f.label :done do" if you want to use rails helpers, since the label method accepts a block http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper/label

Comment: @arieljuod, I didn't know label took a block, That's cool and makes sense. I'll update my answer.

Comment: note that the %label{:for => 'done'} syntax does not provide the same behavior as the helper, the helper will look for the field's attribute translations and print the attribute name, if you want something similar to the helper you need something like %label{for: :done};Your label for the done attribute;=f.check_box :done;, if not, the label is useless since it only have an input inside but no label text, I'd only recommend the helper unless there's a particular reason not to use it

Answer (score 1):

Your indentations and nesting aren't consistent. I usually go with 2 spaces.

Try:

```
= form_tag :todo do |f|
  %br
    = f.label :done
    = f.check_box :done
    = f.label :title
    = f.text_field :title
  %br
    = f.label :urgent
    = f.check_box :urgent
  %br
    = f.label :important
    = f.check_box :important
  %br
    = f.label :description
   %br
    = f.text_area :description
   %br
    = f.submit "Save"
```

This converts nicely to erb:

```
<%= form_tag :todo do |f| %>
  <br>
    <%= f.label :done %>
    <%= f.check_box :done %>
    <%= f.label :title %>
    <%= f.text_field :title %>
  </br>
  <br>
    <%= f.label :urgent %>
    <%= f.check_box :urgent %>
  </br>
  <br>
    <%= f.label :important %>
    <%= f.check_box :important %>
  </br>
  <br>
    <%= f.label :description %>
  </br>
<% end %>
```